# Salesforce1 on focus on textarea header top is hiding

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I have seen the same, or a similar, issue. The problem I encountered also occurs on a mobile device (Android in this case) with a textarea component at the bottom of a container component that extends below the bottom of the viewable screen.

[image]

When I place the cursor in the textarea component, the soft keyboard appears and pushes the viewable screen upwards.

[image]

When I move the cursor out of the textarea, the soft keyboard disappears, and the viewable portion of the aura component remains in the top half of the screen.

[image]

If I pull the screen downwards, trying to view the top portion of the component, this triggers the refresh action, and the entire app simply reloads.